# .Net Session for load balanced Servers

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, iis, sticky-session

I have LoadBalanced WebServers in .Net. When a user logs in into the website, we are not sure if his next request goes to the same webserver. So will storing asp.net session in SqlServer DB solve the issue of recognizing the user when request switches between servers  .

Comment: In IIS Application request routing, there was a property called Client affinity. Then it will promise same client always get routed to the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per below link, OutProc session is suitable for Load balanced servers.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/inproc-session-state-out-proc-session-state-in-asp-net